# HTML to PDF with mpdf table is not centered

Tags: html, pdf, mpdf

I have used mpdf to output some html to a pdf. I am not sure why mpdf is not inserting a top or right margin on the PDF yet the left side seems to have one:

[image: example of problem]

I want to just have the content in the horiztonal center as it is cutting off text on the right. I also want to have a top margin as top content is being cut off.

Here is the settings I have set right now:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('win-1252', 'Letter', '', '', 10, '', '', '', '', '');
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched my declaration to the following:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('win-1252','Letter', 12, '', 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

This correctly set the margins.